# Why is "Audiences may contain many 'free riders', not making contributions." incorrect?

Tags: relative-clauses

[From an SAT practice test]  The correct answer is "Audiences may contain many 'free riders', who did not make contributions."
I can hear how the second sounds better but can't articulate the rule that it follows that the first example breaks.  Don't we say "He is very generous, making many contributions to charity"? What is the difference?

Comment: Context is required. Could you provide some?

Answer (score 2):

In

- *He is very generous, making many contributions to charity.*

the ing-clause, though in terminal position, after the main clause rather than the subject, does refer to either the subject or that main clause.

In

- **Audiences may contain many 'free riders', not making contributions.*

the role of the negated ing-clause is to *explain* the object referent, and this is generally unacceptable.

Note that

*Audiences may contain many people not making contributions.*

is fine, but here the negated ing-clause is used to *describe* something about the people. Even here, similar sentences can sound unacceptable, or very contrived:

- ??/**I saw John's cat not walking.*
- ??/**I saw John's cat, not walking.*

I'd say

- *Audiences may contain many 'free riders'... people not making contributions.*

uses an explanatory (synonymous) appositive correctly.

I'd also take issue with the given answer as being ludicrously pleonastic.

Comment: I would suggest that the idea behind "...free riders who did not make contributions" being correct is that, for live performances, audience members do not, normally, contribute during the performance having paid for tickets in advance or on the door. Free-riders who are watching a show have not, therefore, made a contribution before the performance started. This would not be true of street performance, however, where money is taken either during or after the performance.

Comment: But the usual dictionary definition is inclusive: [[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/free--rider#:~:text=or%20free%2Drider&text=Informal.,the%20benefits%20of%20union%20activities.)] [Informal]: a person who obtains something without effort or cost. If the SAT people (or perhaps primers) are using a stipulating definition here, they need to rethink their target levels.